# Crack material on Ceramic Object

Tags: materials

Good afternoon, I'm just studying the blender so far, I apologize for probably the simplest question. I have studied a lot of videos on youtube but I didn’t get answers to some questions.

I need to create a material that would give such cracks, as in real photographs (sorry for the permission):

[image]

[image]

With the help of the noise texture, I managed to do this only, while I can adjust both the depth of the crack and its width, which is what I need:

[image]

But I would like the crack not to be so endless and going through the entire object, as you can see in the pictures, the crack goes from the bottom and ends at the top, while for me it goes through the whole object. Please help me come up with a solution to my problem.

Question 2:
At the moment, the gradient texture is in this position.
[image]

I want that when changing the position of the camera, they turn towards the camera. [image]

[image]

Comment: There are many ways, you can use for example a gradient texture with a harsh or constant interpolation between black and white of a color ramp, then position it so that the parts of the crack you want to see are in the white area and those you don't want to see are in the black area. Multiply this with the mix factor for the colors and with the value you plug in the height of the displacement. Or instead of a gradient texture you can split the texture coordinate vector in X, Y, Z and see what suits best, or maybe combine some of those. Texture painting to create a mask might be possible too.

Comment: Okay, for the addition at the end: what you could do is create an empty at the center of the ceramic object, put a _Track to_ constraint on it targeting the camera. Use the empty as object in the _Texture Coordinate_ for the gradient. You maybe have to experiment with the tracking axis and maybe lock some rotation axes if you want it e.g. to only rotate on the Z axis. But still I wonder: this was a solution to hide the crack on specific parts of the ceramic, why do you want them to re-appear? Not that it's important, it just doesn't fit to the first part of the question and I'm too curious ;)

Comment: By the way: if you have a second question, you should post it as a new one since different questions demand different answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gordon pointed out in his comment, because the unwanted part of the "crack" is mostly along the Y-axis, you can use a Gradient Texture, separated on the Y as a "mask" to keep the crack from going down that side. Because the crack affects both  a Normal (Displacement) and a surface texture, you will have to integrate the mask for each. You can "inject" it into your graph as pictured below. Note that though the ColorRamp seems to be set to Constant, it is in fact a very closely clamped "linear", as a straight cutoff will be noticeable, and a blend can "hide" better.

[image: Mask1]

Comment: Yep, that's basically how I did it. I actually switched from linear to constant, because if you place it in a good position the straight cutoff is not so strongly noticeable thanks to displacement etc. and it avoids one particular thing: the cracked enamel will either show the colored outside or the white inside, there is no fading from one color to the other. I didn't have enough time today to elaborate an answer, or else I would have additionally made some slight distortion in the straight cut with a noise texture.

Comment: By the way, did you need the _Separate XYZ_ node? I just used the linear gradient 

Comment: You might not need it in this case - I just put it out of habit - sometimes the axis really makes a difference.

Comment: Definitely... I often use the _Mapping_ node to rotate and move the gradient until I have it where I want it.

Comment: @Christopher Bennett and Gordon Brinkmann, Thank you very much, your solution helped me, this is exactly what I need, or can you tell me more, the gradient texture is always in 1 place, is there any way to attach it to the camera so that it is constantly in the camera's visibility, I tried to attach Texture Coordinate Camera to from Gradient Texture, but that's not what I need.

Comment: @Semyon I'm not sure what you want to achieve... you want the gradient texture to change its position or angle with camera movement? But that would mean the crack will be changed, too?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann, I need a lot of unique cracks, for this I use python and generate in such a way that I shift the texture of the material and change the position of the camera. If you leave everything as it is, then I get a lot of empty shots, because. the camera may be on the other side of the crack. That's why I asked, is it possible somehow to change the position of the gradient texture so that it is always in the direction of the camera.

Comment: @Semyon How do you shift the position of the cracks? Is there no way to shift the gradient in a similar way? And what I don't understand, if the camera is "on the other side of the crack", this means (as I imagine it), the crack stays on the object where it was before. So the same part of the object needs to have the gradient as before - why should that change when the camera moves? Seems I'm completely lost here.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann I explained in more detail what I want in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133156/discussion-between-semyon-and-gordon-brinkmann).